# How to read from a text file, add or delete things in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, readfile

I am making a website with Javascript and I want it to have a text box, where user enters something and it reads from the text file and if it is there, it is going to output it, if it is not going to be there then I want to add it to the list, and if I want to delete something, I want to have another button which will delete the inputted word if it finds it in the list.

I can do the HTML part fine, but I have 0 experience with Javascript and can anyone tell me what functions I should use and how its going to be connected with HTML.

I know that form in HTML, which I will need should have action which is going to be connection from javascript to HTML, but other then that part I do now know how to do it in Javascript.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: And where is that text file? Do you also need to write the changes to that file? The Javascript in your browser cannot write files on the server.

Comment: What you are asking is completly unclear, moreover it doesnt make much sense (you are talking about text box one time and file the next. then you talk about words) Please clarify

Comment: that text file would be in the folder were whole website files are.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reading a file with Node**

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('file.txt', function(err,data) {
  if ( err ) throw err;
  console.log("Contents of file.txt: %s",data);
});
```

> **Saving a file with Node**

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("output.txt", "Hello World!", function(err) {
    if ( err ) return console.log(err);
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Further reading: [Node Filesystem API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html)

Comment: how would I do it with node?

Comment: @comp I've revised the answer, hopefully this helps. Let me know if I can help you in any way. Upvotes appreciated